# Computing border size of GtkFrame when window isn't visible

Tags: linux, gtk, gtk2

I want to compute the left and top border sizes of a `GtkFrame`. I use the following code:

```
static void computeborder(GtkWidget *frame)
{
    GtkAllocation alloc, child_alloc;
    int borderTop, borderLeft;

    gtk_widget_get_allocation(frame, &alloc);
    GTK_FRAME_GET_CLASS(frame)->compute_child_allocation(GTK_FRAME(frame), &child_alloc);

    borderTop = child_alloc.y - alloc.y;
    borderLeft = child_alloc.x - alloc.x;

    printf("BORDER TOP: %d BORDER LEFT %d\n", borderTop, borderLeft);
}
```

This is working fine but *only* if the top-level window hosting the `GtkFrame` is already shown. However, I need to find out about border sizes *before* the top-level window which contains my `GtkFrame` widget is shown.

If the top-level window which contains my `GtkFrame` hasn't been opened yet, `(-1,-1)` is returned in `alloc` and `(1,1)` is returned in `child_alloc`. If the top-level window has already been opened, the correct sizes are returned and I can calculate the border sizes.

However, I need to calculate the border sizes when the top-level window is hidden. So how can I calculate the border sizes of my `GtkFrame` in this case?

I'm using GTK 2.

Comment: Do you need the sizes right away? If you can postpone the calculation until the window has been [realized, mapped, or shown](https://blogs.gnome.org/jnelson/2010/10/13/those-realize-map-widget-signals/), you will probably get the correct allocation data.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't postpone the calculation until the window has been realized. Is there any way to get the sizes before realization?

Answer (score 0):

Those values depends on realization, since they need information about the target display etc. Different displays can in theory have different settings that will make the sizes change.

You can try `gtk_widget_realize()` or `gtk_widget_map()` or both on the toplevel window before requesting the sizes